# ffmpeg spacial cropping troubleshooting

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Updates:

## Successful:

relocated `-strict -2`

```
ffmpeg -i Dwell-2019-09-19_13.23.14.mp4 -filter:v "crop=1366:556:1:212" -strict -2 Dwell_out.mp4
```

## Unsuccesful:

'-strict -2' did not make a difference.

```
ffmpeg -strict -2 -i Dwell-2019-09-19_13.23.14.mp4 -filter:v "crop=1366:556:1:212" Dwell_out.mp4
```

## Original Post

[ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/a/511151/45436) is invoked to crop a .mp4 video of resolution 720X1366.  Specifically the goal is crop out the first 212 rows of the video's pixels:

```
ffmpeg -i Dwell-2019-09-19_13.23.14.mp4 -filter:v "crop=1366:556:1:213" Dwell_out.mp4
```

An .mp4 file of zero bytes is returned along with

> ffmpeg version 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the
>   FFmpeg developers   built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu
>   5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 20160609   configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv   libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100   libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100   libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101   libavdevice    56.  4.100 /
>   56.  4.100   libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101   libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0   libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101   libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101   libpostproc    53.  3.100 /
>   53.  3.100 Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Dwell-2019-09-19_13.23.14.mp4':   Metadata:
>       major_brand     : isom
>       minor_version   : 512
>       compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
>       encoder         : Lavf56.40.101   Duration: 00:00:33.94, start: 0.001333, bitrate: 526 kb/s
>       Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1366x768 [SAR 1:1 DAR 683:384], 518 kb/s, 30 fps,
>   30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
>       Metadata:
>         handler_name    : VideoHandler
>       Stream #0:1(und): Audio: vorbis (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 0 kb/s (default)
>       Metadata:
>         handler_name    : SoundHandler File 'Dwell_out.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y [libx264 @ 0x1cd1600] using SAR=1/1
>   [libx264 @ 0x1cd1600] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3
>   SSE4.2 [libx264 @ 0x1cd1600] profile High, level 3.1 [libx264 @
>   0x1cd1600] 264 - core 148 r2643 5c65704 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec -
>   Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options:
>   cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1
>   psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1
>   8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2
>   threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1
>   interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2
>   b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250
>   keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf
>   mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40
>   aq=1:1.00 [aac @ 0x1cd2560] The encoder 'aac' is experimental but
>   experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to
>   use it.

Where to begin troubleshooting?

Comment: Best start simple and simply add `-strict -2` to your command line.  Mind you it would be just as well to simply copy the audio rather than re-encode it: `-c:a copy`.

Comment: @andrew.46  Thanks for the suggestion.  OP updated.

Comment: Oops, you have put `-strict -2` in the wrong spot, try `ffmpeg -i Dwell-2019-09-19_13.23.14.mp4 -filter:v "crop=1366:556:1:213" -strict -2 Dwell_out.mp4` or better: `ffmpeg -i Dwell-2019-09-19_13.23.14.mp4 -filter:v "crop=1366:556:1:213" -c:a copy Dwell_out.mp4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Your `ffmpeg` is really old

The FFmpeg AAC encoder is no longer considered to be experimental (it's been several years now at least), so you won't need `-strict -2`. You should upgrade and your original command will work. Go to [johnvansickle.com](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/), download and extract `ffmpeg`, and put it in `~/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`, then log out and log in. Or follow a [step-by-step guide to compile `ffmpeg`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

## Vorbis audio in MP4?

That's certainly not common. I don't believe many non-FFmpeg based players will like that.

Otherwise, if it were AAC, which is common for the MP4 container, you could simply add the `-c:a copy` output option to stream copy (re-mux) instead of re-encode.

## If you can't update your ancient `ffmpeg`

Add the `-strict experimental` (or the alias `-strict -2`) output option. Option placement matters, so make sure it is after the input and before the output:

```
ffmpeg -i Dwell-2019-09-19_13.23.14.mp4 -filter:v "crop=1366:556:1:212" -strict experimental Dwell_out.mp4
```

**This is the least recommended option** because you're going to miss out on thousands of bug fixes and improvements: especially to the AAC encoder.

Comment: What is the difference between the johnvansickle.com download and the PPA: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/10/install-ffmpeg-4-0-2-ubuntu-18-0416-04/?

Comment: @gatorback Different authors. Jon only offers a simple executable file. The PPA will integrate it into your package management system: I don't know if it conflicts with the repo ffmpeg. PPA requires addition to your `sources.list`. PPA is FFmpeg 4.1 release branch. Jon's is more recent and offers either a daily snapshot from the current development branch or the latest release version which is FFmpeg 4.2. I don't know what is different in terms of supported external libraries. I wouldn't have to see the console output of the `ffmpeg` command of each.